# How to get other application icon from process pid on iOS system?

Tags: ios, macos, process, pid

I have seen this question:

[How to get the current application icon in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419261/how-to-get-the-current-application-icon-in-ios)

Now i could get application path from process pid, then according the question above,with the code blow,i could not get the application icon.

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:apppath];
NSArray *infostmp = [[bundle infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"CFBundleIconFiles"];
if(infostmp){
     NSString* iconPath = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[infostmp objectAtIndex:0]];
     UIImage*  icon =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:iconPath];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the NSBundle object only in a jailbreak iOS, in a non-jailbreak iOS device, the code:  NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:apppath];  get the bundle is nil. So, you can not get the icon.