# Why is my image view not working and why am I getting a blank screen for this view?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uicollectionview

Using a Photo viewer that displays a photo from a collectionView. Can anyone tell me why the viewer is completely ? The image doesn't get displayed at all. I just get a blank screen. In my storyboard, I have an image view with an outlet in my view controller... Why is nothing getting displayed ?

```
import UIKit
import QuartzCore
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage

class PhotoViewerViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    let goldenWordsYellow = UIColor(red: 247.00/255.0, green: 192.00/255.0, blue: 51.00/255.0, alpha: 0.5)

    var imageURLForViewerController: String = ""

    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    let spinner = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: .White)

    var photoInfo: PictureElement?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setupView()
        loadPhoto()
    }

    func setupView() {
        spinner.center = self.imageView.center
        spinner.color = goldenWordsYellow
        spinner.hidesWhenStopped = true
        spinner.startAnimating()
        view.addSubview(spinner)

        let doubleTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handleDoubleTap:")
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        doubleTapRecognizer.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        view.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapRecognizer)
    }

    func loadPhoto() {

        let image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")

        self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")
        self.imageView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.view.bringSubviewToFront(imageView)
        self.spinner.stopAnimating()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        if photoInfo != nil {
            navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
        }
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(true, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: Try adding the extension to the image name.  Ex. "AppIcon.png"  or which ever the extension is of the image.

Answer (score 0):

Try by including the app icon size like these "AppIcon29x29". It works for me. Hope this help! Thanks

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon29x29")
```

or

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon40x40")
```

or

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon60x60")
```

Comment: `self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")` as you can see the original question already has the code you've provided.

Comment: @Alexander Mayatsky ... Please see my answer carefully and see the difference between "AppIcon" and "AppIcon29x29" , "AppIcon40x40",  "AppIcon60x60".
It really works for me on my projects. Thank you

Comment: Yes, you are correct, this is indeed a way to get an AppIcon as opposed to image from assets. You should at least give an explanation then :) Here is another answer precisely describing this case: http://stackoverflow.com/a/22808666/3792318

Comment: Glad to hear that this works for you. And also, I am really sorry for my poor english.
Then, please remove down vote. So that it can be helpful for others. Thank you so much for your quick reply