# Accessing Launch and AppIcon Image programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, assets

I was looking into to fetch appIcon and App Launch image programmatically in the app, to recreate a Splash Screen. 
The entire code is written in objective C

I knew that if any image is present in assets library, I would be able to fetch it via the asset name itself, i.e. `[UIImage imageNamed:"-your-asset-name"]`. 
But I failed when I tried for appIcon/LaunchImage.

Although the workaround would be to store the images in separates asset folders, i.e. I can keep the app icon as a custom image within the same asset as well as in the corresponding appIcon and LaunchImage assets.  and access it, I was wondering why the simple accessing of app icon/launch image is failing, as I am unable to find any supporting docs from Apple.

Can anyone clarify this part.

P.S: I just looked into [How to get UIImage of AppIcon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808416/how-to-get-uiimage-of-appicon) and found that `[UIImage imageNamed:@"AppIcon40x40"]` does provide me the appIcon. However that doesn't work for LaunchImage.

Look into this link for solutions
[iOS 7 / Xcode 5: Access device launch images programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410066/ios-7-xcode-5-access-device-launch-images-programmatically)

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410066/ios-7-xcode-5-access-device-launch-images-programmatically

Comment: Thanks. The loop function answer of Daniel Witurna does work. It's because of the launch image naming conventions.