# How do I include iOS App Icon image within the app itself?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have standard iOS app, with a standard app icon contained in Assets.

I'd like to display the app icon within the app (using SwiftUI).  Note that I am not asking how to set the app icon, or change the icon dynamically.  I just want to show the app icon within the app's own Settings view.

It would appear the App Icon asset should just be like any other, and I could include it using the following (note there is no space between App and Icon in the default icon naming),

```
Image("AppIcon")
```

I've also tried experimenting with,

```
Image("icon_60pt@3x.png") // Pick out a specific icon by filename
Image("icon_60pt@3x") // Maybe it assumes it's a .png
Image("icon_60pt") // Maybe it auto picks most appropriate resolution, like UIKit
```

...but none of these work.

How do I include the apps own icon within the app, without duplicating it as a separate Image Set (which I have tried, and does work.)

Thanks.

Comment: Use different resolutions with "AppIcon".
[Check this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22808416/how-to-get-uiimage-of-appicon)

Comment: @JeanR According to comment on the linked thread, specifying the size no longer works (and it doesn't work for me), but thank you.

Answer (score 22):

The following works *if* app icon is correctly set for used device (ie. iPhone icons for iPhone, etc.)

*Note: sizes of app icons must match exactly!*

Tested with Xcode 11.4

[image: demo1]

[image: demo2]

```
Image(uiImage: UIImage(named: "AppIcon") ?? UIImage())
```

Comment: This works, and @JeanR added how to use specific resolutions, so All Good, thank you.

Comment: This works but I can't load AppIcon-1 and more icons like this...

Comment: @JeanR's doesn't work in the previews though, this one does

Comment: And, since searches will likely lead here, for macOS, replace `uiImage: UIImage` with `nsImage: NSImage`.

Answer (score 10):

This works:

```
extension Bundle {
    var iconFileName: String? {
        guard let icons = infoDictionary?["CFBundleIcons"] as? [String: Any],
              let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as? [String: Any],
              let iconFiles = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? [String],
              let iconFileName = iconFiles.last
        else { return nil }
        return iconFileName
    }
}

struct AppIcon: View {
    var body: some View {
        Bundle.main.iconFileName
            .flatMap { UIImage(named: $0) }
            .map { Image(uiImage: $0) }
    }
}
```

You can then use this in any view as just:

```
AppIcon()
```