# How to render a visionOS icon in a view?

Tags: swiftui, icons, visionos

I want to include an *about* page in my visionOS App, and this should include the App icon. However, the image of the icon does not render.

I have tried using the image statement as suggested in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62063972/how-do-i-include-ios-app-icon-image-within-the-app-itself) and also in this excellent [blog](https://www.polpiella.dev/show-app-icon-and-version-in-a-swiftui-view), but the icon does not appear.

Example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "globe")
                .imageScale(.large)
                .foregroundStyle(.tint)
            Text("Hello, world!")
            if let imageiOS = UIImage(named: "AppIcon") {
                Label(
                    title: { Text("Works") },
                    icon: { Image(systemName: "sun.max.fill")}
                )
                Image(uiImage: imageiOS)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
            }
         
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

This works with iOS, but not VisionOS.

[iOS simulation - icon rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9p8t.png)

[visionOS simulation - no icon rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N37BU.png)

I can see in the visionOS simulator that the 3D icon resource is interpreted correctly when used as a home-screen Icon.

[icon rendered correctly in visionOS homescreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6n2DC.png)

[visionOS icon in Xcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXoYN.png)

Answer (score 2):

[image]

I tested a rendering of a multilayer visionOS icon in a full immersive space. As you can see, everything works fine. In your case, the problem could arise if you used a volumetric window, since the icon could be outside the volume. Also, to get to the desired layer, you should specify a correct path (for instance: `"AppIcon/Layer/Content"`).

```
import SwiftUI

@main struct YourApp : App {
    var body: some Scene {
        ImmersiveSpace() {
            ContentView()
        }
        .immersionStyle(selection: .constant(.full), in: .full)
    }
}
```

[image]

import SwiftUI
import RealityKit

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "camera.circle.fill")
                .imageScale(.large)
            
            Label(title: { Text("It really works") },
                   icon: { Image(systemName: "lightbulb.max.fill") })
            
            ZStack {
                Image("AppIcon/Back/Content")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                Image("AppIcon/Middle/Content")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
                Image("AppIcon/Front/Content")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 150, height: 150)
            }               
            Text("visionOS icon")
        }
        .offset(z: -2000)              // move along the -Z axis
        .padding(.bottom, 2500)        // move along the +Y axis
    }
}
```

Comment: Andy, I can't see from your code if the AppIcon is a 3-layer icon as stipulated by Apple or simply a one layer png. 
In the event I followed your approach specifying a 1-layer png to render in the about screen (called "AboutIcon") and a 3 separate 3-layer icon for the App icon. Not a pretty solution duplicating the icon like this but it worked.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Jazz. I had problems using ImmersiveSpace but I followed your idea with the z offset and staggered the layers by 20px which did yield a primitive 3d rendering,