# How do I debug SwiftUI AttributeGraph cycle warnings?

Tags: xcode, macos, debugging, swiftui

I'm getting a lot of AttributeGraph cycle warnings in my app that uses SwiftUI. Is there any way to debug what's causing it?

This is what shows up in the console:

```
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 11640 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 14168 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 14168 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 44568 ===
=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 3608 ===
```

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using? I had this issue happen in Xcode 11.4 and it miraculously resolved it self in later versions.

Comment: Happens in both Xcode 11.4 and 12 beta 2.

Comment: I just tried mine in Xcode 12 Beta 2 and I don't get it for my code, trying it in 11.4 the issue is still there. I wonder if it is just an Xcode issue...are you able to create a reproducible example that you could share with Apple as a [feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/)? My issue was caused by setting a view in a UIViewRepresentable to be hidden.

Comment: I can probably create a reproducible example, but the reason I'm asking here is because I'm looking for a better way than "just removing stuff until it works" kinda debugging.

Comment: That kind of debugging does suck. I am sorry I don't have a better solution for you. I would be interesting in finding out if there is a way to debug the attribute graph, cause it took me a while to figure out what was causing it.

Comment: Would you add some demo code to get this issue, `cause I did not meet it for a long time?

Comment: So what is causing this issue?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The log is generated by (from private *AttributeGraph.framework*)

```
AG::Graph::print_cycle(unsigned int) const ()
```

so you can set symbolic breakpoint for `print_cycle`

[image: demo]

and, well, how much it could be helpful depends on your scenario, but definitely you'll get error generated stack in Xcode.

Comment: That is very useful. Thanks! How did you find out where the warning message was generated from?

Comment: `$ nm /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AttributeGraph.framework/AttributeGraph`

Comment: How do I get from the breakpoint to information I can do something with? What is attribute %u ===\n"? All of this is situated well ahead of [NSApplication run] and I cannot work out what the offending attribute might be. The documentation I could find is somewhat sparse and only says 'you can set breakpoints'.

Answer (score 15):

For me this issue was caused by me disabling a text field while the user was still editing it.

To fix this, you must first resign the text field as the first responder (thus stopping editing), and *then* disable the text field.
I explain this more in this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69653554/get-attributegraph-cycle-detected-error-when-changing-disabled-state-of-text/69653555#69653555).

Answer (score 2):

For me, this issue was caused by trying to focus a `TextField` right before changing to the tab of a TabView containing the `TextField`.

It was fixed by simply focusing the `TextField` **after** changing the `TabView` tab.

This seems similar to what [@wristbands was experiencing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69653626/2064473).

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was resolved by not using UIActivityIndicator... not sure why though. The component below was causing problems.

```
public struct UIActivityIndicator: UIViewRepresentable {
   
   private let style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style
   
   /// Default iOS 11 Activity Indicator.
   public init(
      style: UIActivityIndicatorView.Style = .large
   ) {
      self.style = style
   }
   
   public func makeUIView(
      context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UIActivityIndicator>
   ) -> UIActivityIndicatorView {
      return UIActivityIndicatorView(style: style)
   }
   
   public func updateUIView(
      _ uiView: UIActivityIndicatorView,
      context: UIViewRepresentableContext<UIActivityIndicator>
   ) {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Asperi Here is a minimal example to reproduce `AttributeGraph cycle`:

```
import SwiftUI

struct BoomView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Go back to see \"AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute\"")
                .font(.title)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}


struct TestView: View {
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State private var isSearchFieldFocused: Bool = false
    
    var placeholderText = NSLocalizedString("Search", comment: "")
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                FocusableTextField(text: $text, isFirstResponder: $isSearchFieldFocused, placeholder: placeholderText)
                    .foregroundColor(.primary)
                    .font(.body)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                
                NavigationLink(destination: BoomView()) {
                    Text("Boom")
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .onAppear {
                self.isSearchFieldFocused = true
            }
            .onDisappear {
                isSearchFieldFocused = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`FocusableTextField.swift` based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/59059359/659389

```
import SwiftUI

struct FocusableTextField: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding public var isFirstResponder: Bool
    @Binding public var text: String
    var placeholder: String = ""

    public var configuration = { (view: UITextField) in }

    public init(text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>, placeholder: String = "", configuration: @escaping (UITextField) -> () = { _ in }) {
        self.configuration = configuration
        self._text = text
        self._isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        self.placeholder = placeholder
    }

    public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextField {
        let view = UITextField()
        view.placeholder = placeholder
        view.autocapitalizationType = .none
        view.autocorrectionType = .no
        view.addTarget(context.coordinator, action: #selector(Coordinator.textViewDidChange), for: .editingChanged)
        view.delegate = context.coordinator
        return view
    }

    public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextField, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
        switch isFirstResponder {
        case true: uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        case false: uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }

    public func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator($text, isFirstResponder: $isFirstResponder)
    }

    public class Coordinator: NSObject, UITextFieldDelegate {
        var text: Binding<String>
        var isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>

        init(_ text: Binding<String>, isFirstResponder: Binding<Bool>) {
            self.text = text
            self.isFirstResponder = isFirstResponder
        }

        @objc public func textViewDidChange(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.text.wrappedValue = textField.text ?? ""
        }

        public func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = true
        }

        public func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
            self.isFirstResponder.wrappedValue = false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the question? This does not look like an answer but an example that produces an AttributedGraph cycle.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I was dynamically loading the AppIcon asset from the main bundle. See [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73688227/4075379) for in-depth details.

Answer (score 0):

I was using enum cases as tag values in a TabView on MacOS. The last case (of four) triggered three attributeGraph cycle warnings. (The others were fine).
I am now using an Int variable (`InspectorType.book.typeInt` instead of `InspectorType.book`) as my selection variable and the cycle warnings have vanished.

(I can demonstrate this by commenting out the offending line respectively by changing the type of my selection; I cannot repeat it in another app, so there's obviously something else involved; I just haven't been able to identify the other culprit yet.)