# Using @FocusState on a TextField causing memory leaks

Tags: ios, swift, memory-leaks, malloc, automatic-ref-counting

I am learning memory and ARC since a while and managed to use the Leaks instrument more often in order to produce quality code. Having that said, please consider my lack of experience in this zone.

Problem: I built a parent view **A** that presents a view **B**.

**B** contains a login form built using a `TextField`, a `SecureField` and a `Button`. I also have a `@FocusState private var isFocused: Bool` property that helps me hide the keyboard in order to bypass the "AttributeGraph: cycle detected" console error that shows up once I disable the textfield on button press having the keyboard on screen. ([Get `AttributeGraph: cycle detected` error when changing disabled state of text field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69653554/get-attributegraph-cycle-detected-error-when-changing-disabled-state-of-text))

I noticed that **when I use** the `@FocusState` property, once I dismiss **B**, the Leaks instrument detects two "Malloc 32 Bytes" leaks just like in the picture below.

If I don't use the `@FocusState` property, the leaks will no longer show up. Am I doing something wrong or is this some kind of bug / false positive from Swift?

[image]

***This view is partially extracted from my file so it doesn't have all it's properties and methods here***.

```
struct AuthenticationLoginView: View {
       
    @StateObject var viewModel = AuthenticationLoginViewModel()
    
    @FocusState private var isFocused: Bool
    
    var body: some View {
            VStack {
                TextField(text: $viewModel.username) {
                    Text("placeholder.")
                }
                .tag(AuthenticationLoginField.username)
                .textInputAutocapitalization(.never)
                .focused($isFocused)
                .disabled(viewModel.isLoggingIn)
                SecureField(text: $viewModel.password) {
                    Text("Password")
                }
//                .focused($isFocused)
                .disabled(viewModel.isLoggingIn)
                .tag(AuthenticationLoginField.password)
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more code it is hard to tell what else you are doing that may have caused the leak.

My gut is that having a single focus boolean when you have two edit fields is an anti-pattern compared to [Apple's way](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/focusstate). When something is evolving like SwiftUI, try to follow their example styles more closely. Use a boolean only when there's just one focusable field.

This similar [Hacking with Swift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-focusstate-property-wrapper) sample shows using an optional and changing the focus as fields submitted.

```
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    @State private var username = "Anonymous"
    @State private var password = "sekrit"

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Enter your username", text: $username)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .username)

            SecureField("Enter your password", text: $password)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .password)
        }
        .onSubmit {
            if focusedField == .username {
                focusedField = .password
            } else {
                focusedField = nil
            }
        }
```

Comment: Just discovered that also Apple's example leaks memory. Tried both Apple's example and the one from Hacking with Swift in a new project. Maybe it's going to be fixed in a future release. Currently using Xcode 13.4.

Comment: Log a Radar on it. Also, is it a real "leak" every time you show that screen, or just an allocation of two blocks that aren't cleaned up until app exit? There are a lot of false positives in leak monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

I found this problem. In my case, it caused a massive retain loop which fed all the way back to coordinator with a bunch of objects.

Just showing a TextField with focus (either the bool way, or the enum way) caused a retain.

My fix was to use the introspect library and just set first responder manually

```
@State private var textField:UITextField?
@State private var secureTextField:UITextField?


var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        TextField(prompt, text: $text)
            .opacity(isSecure ? 0 : 1)
            .introspectTextField { field in
                textField = field
            }
        
        SecureField(prompt,text: $text)
            .opacity(isSecure ? 1 : 0)
            .introspectTextField { field in
                secureTextField = field
            }
    }
    .animation(.easeInOut, value: isSecure)
    .overlay(alignment: .trailing) {
        Button {
            isSecure.toggle()
            setFocus()
        } label: {
            Image(isSecure ? "eyeClose" : "eyeOpen")
        }
        .opacity(canBeSecure ? 1 : 0)
    }
    .onAppear {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            setFocus()
        }
        
    }

    
}

func setFocus() {
    
    if isSecure {
        secureTextField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
    else {
        textField?.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```