# SwiftUI Crash in AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::Emitter

Tags: swiftui, crash, ios13.3

I'm trying to find the problem that causes this crash only on iOS 13.2 - 13.3 devices:

```
3
AttributeGraph
AG::precondition_failure(char const*, ...) + 192
4
AttributeGraph
AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::Emitter<AG::vector<unsigned char, 512ul> >::operator()(AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::EqualsItem const&) + 214
5
AttributeGraph
AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::Emitter<AG::vector<unsigned char, 512ul> >::operator()(AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::EqualsItem const&) + 124
6
AttributeGraph
AG::LayoutDescriptor::Builder::commit(AG::swift::metadata const*) + 152
7
AttributeGraph
AG::LayoutDescriptor::make_layout(AG::swift::metadata const*, AGComparisonMode, AG::LayoutDescriptor::HeapMode) + 320
8
AttributeGraph
AG::(anonymous namespace)::LayoutCache::drain_queue(void*) + 152
```

Does anyone know what might cause this issue?

Comment: Next might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63018486/12299030.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it does not hit that breakpoint.

Comment: I updated that solution to hit make_layout() but it does not help me.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I fixed this issue by conforming the rootView to Equatable protocol.