# SwiftUI crash AttributeGraph precondition failure: invalid attribute id: 83753

Tags: swiftui

I got this (not particularly helpful, in my eyes) crash message and was wondered what the usual suspect was for this/where I'm best to look? I'm getting this when I navigate using a NavigationLink to another View. I know from some research that this crash tends to have a different cause each time, but I wondered if the stack trace would give any clues?

Each crash companies about the same invalid attribute id: 83753. Any way I can track something down using this ID?

```
Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x1c1f2584c __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x1de7f09e8 pthread_kill + 212
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x19ed5c8f4 abort + 100
3  AttributeGraph                 0x1bd82dc7c util::Heap::Heap(void*, unsigned long, unsigned long) + 186
4  AttributeGraph                 0x1bd8269f0 AG::AttributeID::size() const + 238
5  AttributeGraph                 0x1bd82d530 AGGraphGetValue + 500
6  SwiftUI                        0x19c9e4eb0 ResolvedTextFilter.updateValue() + 56
7  SwiftUI                        0x19c4cee34 partial apply for specialized implicit closure #2 in implicit closure #1 in closure #1 in closure #1 in Attribute.init<A>(_:) + 20
8  AttributeGraph                 0x1bd81714c AG::Graph::UpdateStack::update() + 484
9  AttributeGraph                 0x1bd81755c AG::Graph::update_attribute(AG::data::ptr<AG::Node>, bool) + 328
10 AttributeGraph                 0x1bd81c1f8 AG::Graph::value_ref(AG::AttributeID, AGSwiftMetadata const*, bool*) + 152
11 AttributeGraph                 0x1bd82d468 AGGraphGetValue + 300
12 SwiftUI                        0x19c6321d8 ViewGraph.sizeThatFits(_:) + 212
13 SwiftUI                        0x19ca285e0 closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.sizeThatFits(_:) + 52
14 SwiftUI                        0x19c5d2ec4 thunk for @callee_guaranteed (@guaranteed ViewGraph) -> (@unowned CGSize) + 24
15 SwiftUI                        0x19ca2687c closure #1 in ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A>(body:) + 92
16 SwiftUI                        0x19ca1f0b4 ViewRendererHost.updateViewGraph<A>(body:) + 88
17 SwiftUI                        0x19ca25328 ViewRendererHost.sizeThatFits(_:) + 112
18 SwiftUI                        0x19cb7b980 _UIHostingView.sizeThatFits(_:) + 112
19 SwiftUI                        0x19cb7b9c8 @objc _UIHostingView._baselineOffsets(at:) + 48
20 UIKitCore                      0x197eadbb0 -[_UITAMICAdaptorView updateForAvailableSize] + 120
21 UIKitCore                      0x197eadafc -[_UITAMICAdaptorView didMoveToWindow] + 60
22 UIKitCore                      0x198dcdbc0 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 2016
23 UIKitCore                      0x198dcd680 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 672
24 UIKitCore                      0x198dcd680 -[UIView(Internal) _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 672
25 UIKitCore                      0x197ed2350 -[UINavigationBar _didMoveFromWindow:toWindow:] + 64
26 UIKitCore                      0x198dc1ac8 __45-[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:]_block_invoke + 136
27 UIKitCore                      0x198dc19b4 -[UIView(Hierarchy) _postMovedFromSuperview:] + 748
28 UIKitCore                      0x198dd0028 -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:] + 2132
29 UIKitCore                      0x1981385d8 -[UILayoutContainerView addSubview:] + 64
30 UIKitCore                      0x1981434a0 -[UINavigationController _unhideNavigationBarForEdge:] + 100
31 UIKitCore                      0x1981436e8 -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edge:duration:] + 216
32 UIKitCore                      0x198142d30 -[UINavigationController _setNavigationBarHidden:edgeIfNotNavigating:duration:] + 516
33 UIKitCore                      0x1981416ac -[UINavigationController setNavigationBarHidden:animated:] + 156
34 SwiftUI                        0x19cadace8 NavigationBridge_PhoneTV.hostingControllerWillAppear(transitionCoordinator:animated:) + 876
35 SwiftUI                        0x19c53fc60 _UIHostingView.viewControllerWillAppear(transitionCoordinator:animated:) + 48
36 SwiftUI                        0x19cb7fd20 UIHostingController.viewWillAppear(_:) + 116
37 SwiftUI                        0x19cb7fc3c @objc UIHostingController.viewWillAppear(_:) + 40
38 UIKitCore                      0x198210a4c -[UIViewController _setViewAppearState:isAnimating:] + 604
39 UIKitCore                      0x1982111d0 -[UIViewController __viewWillAppear:] + 116
40 UIKitCore                      0x19813f7e8 -[UINavigationController _startCustomTransition:] + 1344
41 UIKitCore                      0x198153bb0 -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded:] + 700
42 UIKitCore                      0x198154fe0 -[UINavigationController __viewWillLayoutSubviews] + 164
43 UIKitCore                      0x198137e78 -[UILayoutContainerView layoutSubviews] + 224
44 UIKitCore                      0x198dd6398 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 2468
45 QuartzCore                     0x1992dbdf4 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 288
46 QuartzCore                     0x1992e2398 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 520
47 QuartzCore                     0x1992ed6e8 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 140
48 QuartzCore                     0x199238d7c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 416
49 QuartzCore                     0x199262f40 CA::Transaction::commit() + 728
50 QuartzCore                     0x1992641f0 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 92
51 CoreFoundation                 0x195fe087c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 32
52 CoreFoundation                 0x195fdaf50 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 604
53 CoreFoundation                 0x195fdb498 __CFRunLoopRun + 960
54 CoreFoundation                 0x195fdaba0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572
55 GraphicsServices               0x1acd43598 GSEventRunModal + 160
56 UIKitCore                      0x1988cc2f4 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052
57 UIKitCore                      0x1988d1874 UIApplicationMain + 164
58 SwiftUI                        0x19ca5a5dc closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 108
59 SwiftUI                        0x19ca5a56c runApp<A>(_:) + 176
60 SwiftUI                        0x19c62bd18 static App.main() + 96
61 ProgressioniOS                 0x10077f06c static ProgressionApp.$main() (<compiler-generated>)
62 ProgressioniOS                 0x10077f39c main (ProgressionApp.swift)
63 libdyld.dylib                  0x195cb9568 start + 4
```

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: It does not help us and you without having the codes that make this issue!

Comment: This can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/63018486/12299030.

Comment: Thanks @Asperi - Once again rescued by you! :)