# How to get IOS current alternate icon name?

Tags: ios, appicon

My app supports alternative icons and I have speicified CFBundleAlternateIcons inside CFBundleIcons. But how can I get current used icon info?

I have tried this [How to get the current application icon in ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419261/how-to-get-the-current-application-icon-in-ios). But it doesn't work for me.

Anyone helps? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Get the name of the icon being displayed for the app**

If you want to know which icon is being displayed, just read `alternateIconName` on `UIApplication` shared instance:

```
let currentIcon = UIApplication.shared.alternateIconName
```