# I can't find my AppIcon in the main bundle

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have this piece of code ...

```
guard let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AppIcon", ofType: "png") else {
        print("Image not found")
        return nil
    }
```

This is returning nil, which I can't seem to figure out. I assume my file path is wrong. Any suggestions? [image]

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access a folder `AppIcon`, with the extension `png`? Try changing the `ofType` to `.appiconset`.

Comment: Hi check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9419261/how-to-get-the-current-application-icon-in-ios) answer, could help you

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I hope this may be helpful to you.

```
extension Bundle {
 public var icon: UIImage? {
    if let icons = infoDictionary?["CFBundleIcons"] as? [String: Any],
        let primaryIcon = icons["CFBundlePrimaryIcon"] as? [String: Any],
        let iconFiles = primaryIcon["CFBundleIconFiles"] as? [String],
        let lastIcon = iconFiles.last {
        return UIImage(named: lastIcon)
    }
    return nil
  }
}
```

**You can use it in your app like this:**

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.image = Bundle.main.icon
```

Comment: I'm using let attachement = try? UNNotificationAttachment(identifier: "attachment", url: fileURL, options: nil), so i need the url. I tried the extension with iconFiles.last, but still couldn't get it. It's returning nil. Just can't figue it out.